# AWS DynamoDB : Why does "Keys Only" projection not include the Sort Key of the Table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was reading the [official](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) documentation for AWS' GSI. In the documentation they are indicating that the GameScores table has a Primary Key (`UserID`) and a Sort Key(`GameTitle`). They then create a GSI called **GameTitleIndex** on `GameTitle` and `TopScore` with KEYS ONLY projection - they mention that the new GSI will have `GameTitle` and `TopScore` AS WELL the primary key attributes projected.

But they ONLY indicate that `UserID` (And not `GameTitle`) is projected. They even show a diagram of the GSI where only `UserID` is shown and not `GameTitle`.
Isn't `GameTitle` a Key attribute (since its a COMPOSITE Primary Key?) and shouldn't BOTH `UserID` and `GameTitle` have been projected on the GSI?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`GameTitle` is right there as the partition key in the GSI. It's not going to appear twice. An attribute acting as a key is still present.

Comment: beat me to the Post button...

Comment: oh for gods sakes... ive had a brain fart... thanks  guys!! my mind was befuddling the GameTile for some reason as two separate entitites.